# Two Materials on Object - Only One Material is Rendering (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, hair

I've very new to Blender (only a few weeks) so I'm guessing these are rookie mistakes. I created this crocheted dragon, first by adding a "crochet" image texture with a displacement as well. Then I added a hair particle to the body of the dragon and as a second material to create the fuzz of the "crochet" fabric. The 3D viewport render view looks great to me but when I do an actual render of the object, only the hair particle material is rendering and the crochet is not (Cycles - Blender 2.83)

[image]

When I render the object, only the hair particle material is rendering.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best, Dale

**ANSWER(edit): Susu was correct. I did not have "Show Emitter" enabled in my Particle Settings. That fixed the issue.**

Comment: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles Could you provide your system specs and rendering settings (render engine, tile size etc.)?

Comment: I have removed my second question. Thank you both for your comments. Still need help on my initial question, above.

Comment: In the particle settings>render is the show emitter box enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that like material is there, but is hidden under hairs because you have set in Properties >
*Viewport Display* > **Amount** like 10% of hairs, but 100% is rendered?

[image]

If Susu is right, I will delete my A.

Comment: please don't delete your answer!

Comment: Susu, the "show emitter" box was not enabled. I enabled it and that fixed the issue. Thank you very much!